# Adding App Specific Entry into the Android Settings Menu

Tags: android

As I know, we can add our app specific menu entries in iPhone's Settings menu. I want to know how same can be done in Android? I am developing for Android 1.6 using Eclipse Galileo. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the closest thing to what you seek is the Account Authenticator feature. For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658330/show-settings-under-accounts-sync-menu-for-android-app) and look for the android:accountPreferences attribute. This allows your preference Activity to show up in the Accounts area of Settings.

Apart from that, while it's difficult to prove a negative, I've analyzed the Settings source code for Jelly Bean and I'm pretty certain this is impossible. To see for yourself, examine the onBuildHeaders() method in the Settings.java file. The headers array is maintained internally to the Settings Activity and the only flexibility seems to be the Account mechanism mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Read the details information from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) .

Nice one example [here](http://jmdonovan.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/android-%E2%80%93-with-eclipse-v3-5-ide-app%E2%80%99s-menu-adding-a-%E2%80%9Cmenu%E2%80%9D-at-the-bottom-of-the-app-screen/).

Comment: Its shows how to use or share menus in or between apps. I want my app settings to be accessible from Android's built in Settings menu.

Answer (score 1):

Use android:settingsActivity in your Manifest. It works for Livewallpaper or Input Method. You can't use it for everything or for your particular App.

Answer (score 1):

You will find this good for you.[Check this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html)

this will let you know many options to customize your App

Have a Look @ this link[PreferenceActivity .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027771/using-a-listview-to-create-a-settings-screen-in-android)

Comment: Though it doesn't answers my query, but its nice reference. Thanks. :)

Comment: welcome.Your post seems to be very interesting. So can you provide some details on your implementation setting

Comment: Have you checked PreferenceActivity . Have a look @ this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027771/using-a-listview-to-create-a-settings-screen-in-android