# Android : Add your own application to accounts

Tags: android

I looking to learn how to add own application in "Accounts" tab in Settings. I have no idea about how it is called. I am open for all kind of informations, basic tutorials and github projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is how to write an Authenticator. See for instance [this tutorial](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/), which also points to it's own [GitHub project](https://github.com/Udinic/AccountAuthenticator) which implements a sample authenticator.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658330/show-settings-under-accounts-sync-menu-for-android-app) for a simple answer of the question. The official guide for authenticators is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html).