# Is there an official Android section View?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

List sections are used quite a lot in Android through out Google's own applications and in some of the framework's features as well, i.e. preferences.

This made me wonder if there is an offical section `View` available in Android? If so, it seems to be hidden.

Here's a picture from the [Android Design site](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) that shows what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027771/using-a-listview-to-create-a-settings-screen-in-android

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how that's helpful.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such view. Anyway why do you need one? It is very easy to implement.

Comment: Yep, it's pretty easy to implement, I just wanted to make use of the official one, if such was available :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This made me wonder if there is an offical section View available in Android?

No, sorry. There are plenty of libraries for this, and you can probably grab some code out of AOSP for it as well, but there is nothing in the SDK for it. Just because the design folk think it is a good idea does not mean that we actually have code in the SDK to leverage such ideas.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. That's pretty much what I thought.

Comment: Well I was thinking the same but since I dont have 221K I can't dare to answer it :(

Comment: Google I/O schedule application implements it like this http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SimpleSectionedListAdapter.java